# Get value from another static table when "ID_ENTE_COMPETENZA_TIPO" is equal to 'S' in an dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, lookup, .when

i have a simple dataframe like:

```
df
    id_ente_competenza_tipo | INOLTRO_PSAP2 
       3                           S    
       3                           S
       3                           N
       2                           S
```

i have another dataframe static table:

```
df_ente
id_ente_competenza_tipo| des_ente_competenza_tipo
  1                       Carabinieri
  2                       Polizia di Stato
  3                       Emergenza Sanitaria
```

i want that if df.ID_ENTE_COMPETENZA_TIPO =='S' --> df.ID_ENTE_COMPETENZA_TIPO =df_ente.des_ente_competenza_tipo where df.id_ente_competenza_tipo ==df_ente.id_ente_competenza_tipo otherwise df.id_ente_competenza_tipo

i want this:

```
id_ente_competenza_tipo |    INOLTRO_PSAP2 
         Emergenza Sanitaria      S    
         Emergenza Sanitaria      S
         3                        N
         Polizia di Stato         S
```

my code is this but there is amoreefficient way?

```
df=df.withColumn("ID_ENTE_COMPETENZA_TIPO",F.when(df.INOLTRO_PSAP2=="S",df_ente.join(df,
df_ente["id_ente_competenza_tipo"]==df["ID_ENTE_COMPETENZA_TIPO"])\
.select("des_ente_competenza_tipo").head()[0]).otherwise(df.ID_ENTE_COMPETENZA_TIPO))
```

Thanks for help
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to apply the logic of choosing between `des_ente_competenza_tipo` or `id_ente_competenza_tipo` based on `INOLTRO_PSAP2` after joining the tables. Use the `when and otherwise` you had applied in the code snippet.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(3, "S", ),(3, "S", ),(3, "N", ),(2, "S", ),], ("id_ente_competenza_tipo", "INOLTRO_PSAP2"))

df_ente = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "Carabinieri", ),(2, "Polizia di Stato", ),(3, "Emergenza Sanitaria", ),], ("id_ente_competenza_tipo", "des_ente_competenza_tipo"))


results = df.join(df_ente, ["id_ente_competenza_tipo"])\
  .withColumn("id_ente_competenza_tipo", F.when(df["INOLTRO_PSAP2"] == "N", df["id_ente_competenza_tipo"]).otherwise(df_ente["des_ente_competenza_tipo"]))\
  .select("id_ente_competenza_tipo", "INOLTRO_PSAP2")

results.show()
```

### Output

```
+-----------------------+-------------+
|id_ente_competenza_tipo|INOLTRO_PSAP2|
+-----------------------+-------------+
|       Polizia di Stato|            S|
|    Emergenza Sanitaria|            S|
|    Emergenza Sanitaria|            S|
|                      3|            N|
+-----------------------+-------------+
```